# How to dynamically add a CSS class to a div in a component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a class in the CSS file of a certain component, this class would make some elements in the component not visible. I wanna add this class to the `div` only when I click a button, which happens to be in an entirely different component. I know how I'd do this using Vanilla javascript but with React I'm clueless.
I've decided to make it easier to check it out/edit with,
CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-keldysh-yhw2m?file=/src/components/FaceRecogBox/FaceRecogBox.css
PS: In the FaceRecogBox component I'm trying to add the `.vanish` class to the `main-container` div, using the button in LinkedInput.js

Comment: What do you mean? This is me learning React

Comment: where in your code is the button you want to click to make the div vanish?

Comment: Yeah I've done that and because I don't wanna stay in course hell I'm starting my own projects as a way of learning. Your statement before was kinda... unwarranted

Comment: @Christian Fritz the button in the LinkInput.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../FaceRecogBox/FaceRecogBox.css'

const FaceRecogBox = ({ imageUrl, isDivVisible }) => {
    // You should pass the condition as a prop to the FaceRecogBox

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`main-container ${!isDivVisible && "vanish"}`}>
                <div className="brokenlines-container">
                    <h3>Drag and drop to upload <br/> Or <a href="/">browse</a> this device</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="faces">
                <img src={imageUrl} alt="" className="faces"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}

export default FaceRecogBox;
```

I'll leave the link to the [sandbox updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-brook-2zn0x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you also can use the ternary operator to choose between different styles depending on a boolean like `<div className={\`main-container ${!isDivVisible ? "vanish" : "theOtherClass"}\`}>`